# Generate a dynamic table of contents based on (already) rendered headings with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, markdown, templating

Many Wikis have it, a table of contents based on the headings from the displayed page. I'm looking for an easy possibility to realize that with Rails.

I have different kinds of pages, like dynamically generated ones, processed markdown pages as well as static pages. All these pages have HTML headings on different levels. **How can I generate a Wiki like table of contents, which links to the headings with anchors?**

I already searched for a post render callback or another entry point in the life cycle, which is happening after rendering, but I didn't found really one. What would you suggest to do? .. implementing a middle ware or what would be your direction?

Comment: Would you consider doing it with JavaScript after the page is sent to the browser? Chris Coyier's argument that a table of contents is a "bonus" is compelling: http://css-tricks.com/automatic-table-of-contents/

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Chris. I considered this. My only point against it is, if a user has disabled JavaScript, the user wouldn't see the table of contents at all. Maybe there are no such users out there anymore and I should go down that path (?), because this 'topic' is strongly linked to JavaScript anyway. I still hope for someone, who has a rails solution.

Comment: The point is that this sort of thing could be treated as progressive enhancement. The page still works fine without the table of contents. (And in terms of accessibility, the page is still accessible as long as you're using heading tags.) Good luck finding a Rails solution though if that's what you really need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decide to stick with markdown for all your content, you can do this with the [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) gem. Passing `with_toc_data: true` to the renderer will add anchors to header tags. And re-rendering with `Redcarpet::Render::HTML_TOC` will generate a list of links linking to those header tags.